# I just made my altcoin, should I list my source code at Github?

Tags: altcoin

It seems to me that every new coin introduced, they list source code in Github.
Is that customary in the industry?

Comment: Could you please point me to a guide on how did you create it? I have gone through the one on bitcointalk but its very outdated

Answer (score 2):

Most users are not going to trust a closed-source altcoin, so you should make its code available to the public. [This board also doesn't support closed-source cryptocurrencies](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/629/suggestion-closed-source-cryptocurrencies-should-be-off-topic).

[GitHub provides free hosting for open-source projects](https://github.com/blog/11-github-free-for-open-source) and has become a standard in the open source community so (primary opinion-based statement follows) it's probably a good idea to put your code there.